# Java. How to return generalized object?

Tags: java, android, generics

I have a class

```
public class Product {
...
}
```

and

```
public class Phone extends Product {
...
}
```

I want to return a generic object. Now i try that :

```
public <T extends Product> T getProduct()
{
   return new Phone();
}
```

but the compiler give me error :

```
Incompatiple types :
Required : T
Found : Phone
```

What's wrong? And how i can fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generic return? 
If you are looking for a return type which can work for all subtype of Product, then this should work.

```
public Product getProduct() {
   return new Phone();
}
```

Comment: That's right answer. Sorry i missed `extends` in my real construction. :) I will accept in 10 minutes. Stack doesn't allow me do that now :(

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<T extends Product>` by `Product`